# Error saving data from Datatable to MySQL database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, datatable

```
//ADDING NEW ITEM INTO THE ITEM TABLE
$(document).on('submit', '#product_form', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    btn_action="add_pricelvl"; //Set variable to call the add new item 
    var valdata = $(this).serialize();  //Array with field value    
    var tax = $('#item_tax').val(); //checkbox tax 
    var taxvalue = $('#item_taxvalue').val(); //inputbox tax
    var tabledets = it_det //Read the detail table
        .rows()
        .data();
    var arr1=[];
    var i=0;
    //Put the datatable rows in the array
    for (i=0; i<tabledets.length; i++){
        arr1[i]=tabledets.rows(i).data();   
    }
    //call ajax function and send variable to php file.
    $.ajax({    
        url:'item_action.php',
        method:"POST",
        data:{
            btn_action:btn_action, 
            valdata:valdata,
            tax:tax,
            taxvalue:taxvalue,
            arr1:arr1
            },          
        success : function(data)
        {
            $('#product_form')[0].reset();
            $('#productModal').modal('hide');
            $('#alert_action').fadeIn().html('<div class="alert alert-success">'+data+'</div>');
            $('#action').attr('disabled', false);
            $('#item_data').DataTable().ajax.reload();                
        },
        error : function () {
            $('<div>').html('Found an error!');
        }
    })
});
```

That's my java code and I'm trying to call a php page and save all data in my DB. I got an error:

> TypeError: 'insertCell' called on an object that does not implement interface HTMLTableRowElement.

That's happening when I insert data into the table "it_det"

Look the picture:
[image]

If I don't insert new rows into the table I don't get error!
What's wrong with that? Why I'm getting this error???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution changing the "processData" key to false

```
$.ajax({
        processData: false, //The default value of ProcessData is true so changing in false I don't get any error.
        url:'item_action.php',
        method:"POST",
```